# Javascript form element input validation handling

Tags: javascript, validation

I have 2 radio groups: email and system.
I want it to display error message when there is no radio button selected for both of them.
This means, i want it at least 1 radio button is selected from one of the radio groups.

If radio_system button with Create value is selected, i want checkboxes of system and dept are all enabled.
If radio button with Change or Terminate value is selected in email or system group, i want the remark textarea to be enabled.

I know it sounds complicated. But how can i make it works? please help...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#form").validate(
    {
        rules: {
                    radio_email: "required",
                    radio_system: "required",
        remark: "required",
        system: "required",
        dept: "required",
}
    });  
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.block { display: block; }
form.form_class label.error { display: none; }  
</style>

<form id="form" name="form" class="form_class">
<input type="radio"  name="radio_email" value="Create" id="radio_email_0" />New
<input type="radio" name="radio_email" value="Change" id="radio_email_1" />Change
<input type="radio" name="radio_email" value="Terminate" id="radio_email_2" />Termination

<input type="radio" name="radio_system" value="Create" id="radio_system_0" />New
<input type="radio" name="radio_system" value="Change" id="radio_system_1"/>Change
<input type="radio" name="radio_system" value="Terminate" id="radio_system_2" />Termination

<label for="radio_system" class="error">Please select under either Email or System.</label>

<textarea name="remark" id="remark" cols="79" rows="3"></textarea>

<input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="A" id="app_0" />A
<input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="B" id="app_0" />B
<input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="C" id="app_0" />C

<input type="checkbox" name="dept[]" value="A" id="app_0" />A
<input type="checkbox" name="dept[]" value="B" id="app_0" />B
<input type="checkbox" name="dept[]" value="C" id="app_0" />C

<input type="submit" name="submitted_form" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add onClick() handler to all the Radio buttons. Write a javascript function which will be called from onclick() method of all  Radio buttons.
Access the javascript id of all the other elements that you have on GUI and then you can decide what action to take. Hope am clear enough to you.